# Copy values based on match criteria

Tags: excel, vba

[Data Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaMf3.png)

I have two workbooks with the same content. I am copying and pasting the amount values from one workbook sheet to another when the project number and division is the same. The amount has to be pasted in the row where there is a match. The issue I am facing is all the amounts are getting copied but not pasted near the respective match.

The code I have used is as follows:

```
    ws1PRNum = "E"         'Project Number
    ws1Div = "I"        'Division
    ws2PRNum = "E"         'Project Number
    ws2Div = "I"        'Division

    
   'Setting first and last row for the columns in both sheets
    ws1PRRow = 5              'The row we want to start processing first
    ws1EndRow = wsSrc.UsedRange.Rows(wsSrc.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row
    ws2PRRow = 5              'The row we want to start search first
    ws2EndRow = wsDest.UsedRange.Rows(wsDest.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row

For i = ws1PRRow To ws1EndRow        'first and last row
        searchKey = wsSrc.Range(ws1PRNum & i) & wsSrc.Range(ws1Div & i) 'PR line and number is Master Backlog
         'if we have a non blank search term then iterate through possible matches
        If (searchKey <> "") Then
            For j = ws2PRRow To ws2EndRow 'first and last row
                 foundKey = wsDest.Range(ws2PRNum & j) & wsDest.Range(ws2Div & j) 'PR line and number in PR Report
                  'Copy result if there is a match between PR number and line in both sheets
                 If (searchKey = foundKey) Then
                    'Copying data where the rows match
                        wsDest.Range("AJ5", "AU1200").Value = wsSrc.Range("AJ5", "AU1200").Value
                        wsDest.Range("BB5", "BM1200").Value = wsSrc.Range("BB5", "BM1200").Value
                        wsDest.Range("BT5", "BU1200").Value = wsSrc.Range("BT5", "BU1200").Value
                    Exit For
                 End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

This is the area that is causing an issue. As seen in the picture the amounts are pasted even in rows where the division and project number are empty. Any answer for the same would be highly appreciated as I am not well versed with VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```vb
wsDest.Range("AJ" & j, "AU" & j).Value = wsSrc.Range("AJ" & i, "AU" & i).Value
'etc...
```

or with a bit less concatenation:

```vb
wsDest.Rows(j).Range("AJ1:AU1").Value = wsSrc.Rows(i).Range("AJ1:AU1").Value
```